# Scope issue with false-statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement

- Python version: 3.7.3
- TensorFlow version: 2.2.0
- Operating System: Raspbian

I am trying to follow get my Raspberry Pi to successfully scan, then track a RPi camera, following this [repository](https://github.com/leigh-johnson/rpi-deep-pantilt). When I issue the 'rpi-deep-pantilt track Raspi' command, it successfully starts detecting in a stationary position, and when it detects an object, it begins tracking. I need it to scan, making 60deg increments panning back and forth while detecting, so I incorporated the bolded lines into the manager.py script:

```
import logging
from multiprocessing import Value, Process, Manager

import pantilthat as pth
import signal
import sys
**import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO**

**from rpi_deep_pantilt.detect.util.visualization import draw_bounding_box_on_image**
from rpi_deep_pantilt.detect.camera import run_pantilt_detect
from rpi_deep_pantilt.control.pid import PIDController

**#Specifying GPIO Pin name
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(8,GPIO.OUT)**

logging.basicConfig()
LOGLEVEL = logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel()

RESOLUTION = (320, 320)

SERVO_MIN = -90
SERVO_MAX = 90

CENTER = (
    RESOLUTION[0] // 2,
    RESOLUTION[1] // 2
)

# function to handle keyboard interrupt
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    # print a status message
    print("[INFO] You pressed `ctrl + c`! Exiting...")

    # disable the servos
    pth.servo_enable(1, False)
    pth.servo_enable(2, False)
    GPIO.output(8,GPIO.LOW)

    # exit
    sys.exit()


def in_range(val, start, end):
    # determine the input value is in the supplied range
    return (val >= start and val <= end)


def set_servos(pan, tilt):
    # signal trap to handle keyboard interrupt
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    **scan_on=True**
    
    while True:
        pan_angle = -1 * pan.value
        tilt_angle = tilt.value
        
        # if the pan angle is within the range, pan
        if in_range(pan_angle, SERVO_MIN, SERVO_MAX):
            pth.pan(pan_angle)
        else:
            logging.info(f'pan_angle not in range {pan_angle}')

        if in_range(tilt_angle, SERVO_MIN, SERVO_MAX):
            pth.tilt(tilt_angle)
        else:
            logging.info(f'tilt_angle not in range {tilt_angle}')
        
        draw_bounding_box_on_image

        **while scan_on == True:
            pth.servo_one(90)
            pth.servo_two(25)
            time.sleep(10)
            
            pth.servo_one(30)
            pth.servo_two(25)
            time.sleep(10)
            
            pth.servo_one(-30)
            pth.servo_two(25)
            time.sleep(10)
            
            pth.servo_one(-90)
            pth.servo_two(25)
            time.sleep(10)

            continue**
.
.
```

The last few lines are the scanning procedures. They work, but once an object is detected, it doesn't exit the scanning cycle. This is the function of my visualizion.py script that is imported to manager.py:

```
def draw_bounding_box_on_image(image,
                               ymin,
                               xmin,
                               ymax,
                               xmax,
                               color='red',
                               thickness=4,
                               display_str_list=(),
                               use_normalized_coordinates=True):


    **GPIO.output(8,GPIO.HIGH)
    scan_on = False**

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    im_width, im_height = image.size
    if use_normalized_coordinates:
        (left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin * im_width, xmax * im_width,
                                      ymin * im_height, ymax * im_height)
    else:
        (left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    draw.line([(left, top), (left, bottom), (right, bottom),
               (right, top), (left, top)], width=thickness, fill=color)
    try:
        font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 24)
    except IOError:
        font = ImageFont.load_default()

    # If the total height of the display strings added to the top of the bounding
    # box exceeds the top of the image, stack the strings below the bounding box
    # instead of above.
    display_str_heights = [font.getsize(ds)[1] for ds in display_str_list]
    # Each display_str has a top and bottom margin of 0.05x.
    total_display_str_height = (1 + 2 * 0.05) * sum(display_str_heights)

    if top > total_display_str_height:
        text_bottom = top
    else:
        text_bottom = bottom + total_display_str_height
    # Reverse list and print from bottom to top.
    for display_str in display_str_list[::-1]:
        text_width, text_height = font.getsize(display_str)
        margin = np.ceil(0.05 * text_height)
        draw.rectangle(
            [(left, text_bottom - text_height - 2 * margin), (left + text_width,
                                                              text_bottom)],
            fill=color)
        draw.text(
            (left + margin, text_bottom - text_height - margin),
            display_str,
            fill='black',
            font=font)
        text_bottom -= text_height - 2 * margin
    return scan_on
```

I used the GPIO to light up an LED, letting me know when the bounding box has been overlaid on the camera feed. At this point my system should identify that `scan_on = False`, and it should exit the scan cycle and revert to the default tracking mode. My manager.py script must not pick it up because it continues to run the scanning, meaning `scan_on = True`.

Comment: I don't see any code called inside your loop that would change the scan_on variable... So it's an infinite loop.

Comment: And I don't understand what drawing a bounding box has to do with anything here

Comment: You never actually call `draw_bounding_box_on_image` - you merely mention the name of the function, `()` after the name is required to call it.

Comment: @CherryDT I just updated it. After importing my draw_bounding_box_on_image function, I need help calling it in my manager.py script. The bounding symbolizes when an object is detected, as the bounding box is overlaid onto the camera feed at that moment. I want to utilize this point in time to break the scan while loop, which would revert my system back into track mode, that's why 'scan_on = False' is included in the visualization.py script.

Comment: Then instead of having a while scan_on and so on, you should check inside of the loop whether there is an object, call the draw_bounding_box_on_image and break the loop.

Comment: @CherryDT which loop are you talking about?